# Oreo - Notification not received when app is closed but works fine when it's in background

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

**Environment:**

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
```

** Description:**

I am sending FCM notification from a batch program and everything was working fine till version 7.0. Now I have changed the code for Android Oreo (used channels etc.) and here are the test results:

*Till Version 7.0:*

```
 Notification received when App is open? Yes

 Notification received when App is in the background? Yes

 Notification received when App is Closed? Yes
```

*Version 8.1(Oreo):*

```
 Notification received when App is open? Yes

 Notification received when App is in background? Yes

 **Notification received when App is Closed? No**
```

**Code**

```
String channelId =  "abc";
        AudioAttributes audioAttr = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "abc", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription("description");
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.s), audioAttr);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bell)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.cc))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true);

        int notificationId = 1;
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

**Question:**

1. Why am I not getting notifications when the app is closed?
2. Why notification badge is not showing?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? Facing same problem.

Comment: here are my findings. This behavior is mostly visible in Chinese made mobiles like Oppo, Vivo etc. I guess they are not 100% android and they are bit strict about battery usage. On these devices if you leave open the app in the background instead of swiping it out or closing it, notifications works well. In some cases you have to change app notification settings. There is not much you can do except educating your users. If you want 100% reliable notifications then switch to some other APIs like openfire instead of android notifications,

Comment: Did you find a solution?